# CORS preflight response incorrect/empty headers

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, axios

I have cors for `/api/test` set up thusly:

```
Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8133
Allow-Headers: X-MyHeader
Allow-Method: Get
```

i.e.

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8133")
            .WithHeaders("X-MyHeader")
            .WithMethods("GET");
    });
});
```

and

```cs
app.UseCors("default");
```

If I send a get request to `/api/test` with the header `X-MyHeader` using axios it sends an `OPTIONS` request e.g.

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-myheader
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Host: localhost:8132
Origin: http://localhost:8133
```

I receive back

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-myheader
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8133
Date: {whatever}
server: {whatever}
```

Why is the `Access-Control-Allow-Method` header missing?

---

Now if I add another header like, `X-NotSupportedHeader` e.g.

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-notsupportedheader
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Host: localhost:8132
Origin: http://localhost:8133
```

My response is

```
Date: {whatever}
server: {whatever}
```

And in the console we get

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8132/api/test. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8133' is therefore not allowed access.`

Why are no `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers set at all if any of the criteria fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, just read the spec.

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests